# Proteus VSM: digital vs analog resistor and LED

Tags: led, digital-logic, resistors, analog, proteus

I'm a newbie to electricity and electronics in general.  I've been reading about the principles and have a basic understanding of them.  I'm also diving into creating my first basic circuits with Proteus VSM to be able to simulate them and hopefully understand and learn in the process.

The reason I'm mentioning this is that if there's any logical mistake in my question, I'd be awesome if you could point me towards what I need to read about.

**My setup:**
I have a basic circuit using two digital-output MCU pins (using an arduino, two pins in OUTPUT mode), a resistor and a LED that lights up as soon as I run my simulation.

I'm simulating this with Proteus VSM although I believe this question is generic.

**My doubt:**
Proteus VSM allows you to configure the resistor and LED as either analog or digital.

Is there a difference between those setting for resistors and LEDs?  Do these components exist in digital and analog versions?

Comment: No they don't; that sounds like it's a simplification parameter for simulation purposes.

Comment: Thank you!  I'm crediting both yours and the answer below since both provided me with good information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@diegoreymendez is correct. "Analog" simulation is more computationally-intensive than "digital" simulation, to provide for more resolution of what the voltages and currents are actually doing. (It is a fast approximation for "Digital" mode, to speed up simulation.) So set them to Digital if the signals going through them are going to be purely digital, and Analog in all other cases. In this case, the resistor and LED *are* behaving as analog devices, so for the most accurate results, choose Analog. Here is further reading on [Analog-vs-Digital](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/analog-vs-digital).